# Save xts object as csv file

Tags: r, csv, statistics, xts

I loaded a csv file using:

```
data = read.csv(file="/home/stefanos/R/data_frames_new/temp2.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

The first 4 lines of the temp2.csv file are:

```
nodeId,battery,date,idHistoric,temperature,longitude,latitude
3,78.00,2013-04-01 00:04:03,30163676,13.74,-3.80176,43.46192
3,78.00,2013-04-01 00:09:01,30164278,13.67,-3.80176,43.46192
3,78.00,2013-04-01 00:13:59,30164875,13.67,-3.80176,43.46192
```

I want to group it by nodeId and find the mean value of the temperature for every 15 minutes. So I type:

```
df <- xts(x = data[, c("nodeId", "battery", "idHistoric", "temperature", "longitude", "latitude")], order.by = as.POSIXct(data[, "date"], tz = "GMT", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

and then:

```
df2 <- by(df,df$nodeId,function(x){
   ends <- endpoints(x, on = "minutes", k = 15)
   xx    <- period.apply(x, ends, mean)
 })
```

My problem is that I cannot write the df2 to csv file. I have not yet been able to do so.
When I print df2 in screen I see the following structure:

```
/*********************************************/

INDICES: 3
                    nodeId  battery idHistoric temperature longitude latitude
2013-04-01 00:13:59      3 78.00000   30164276    13.69333  -3.80176 43.46192
2013-04-01 00:28:54      3 79.00000   30166075    13.78000  -3.80176 43.46192
[...]
------------------------------------------------------------ 
INDICES: 4
                    nodeId  battery idHistoric temperature longitude latitude
2013-04-01 00:13:07      4 87.00000   30164172    14.42667  -3.80098 43.46199
2013-04-01 00:28:01      4 87.33333   30165964    14.49000  -3.80098 43.46199
------------------------------------------------------------ 
INDICES: 5
                    nodeId  battery idHistoric temperature longitude latitude
2013-04-01 00:13:31      5 83.00000   30164224    13.84667  -3.80058 43.46203
2013-04-01 00:28:26      5 83.66667   30166018    14.06000  -3.80058 43.46203
------------------------------------------------------------ 
INDICES: 6
                    nodeId  battery idHistoric temperature longitude latitude
2013-04-01 00:12:52      6 78.00000   30164128    13.99667  -3.79979 43.46212
2013-04-01 00:28:52      6 79.00000   30165983    13.97333  -3.79979 43.46212

/*********************************************/
```

So how can I save it in CSV?

Comment: `df2` is a list of class "by". Because it's a list you should be able to turn it into a data.frame using `do.call("rbind",df2)`. But without a reproducible example I cannot test ...

Answer (score 3):

You can do this (as mentioned by @Roland in the comment)

```
write.table(do.call(rbind,df2),file='test.csv')
```

Here a complete example with your data. You can use `read.zoo` to create your xts object, in one liner command:

```
library(zoo)
## you replace text= here by file=temp2.csv
dat <- read.zoo(text='nodeId,battery,date,idHistoric,temperature,longitude,latitude
3,78.00,2013-04-01 00:13:59,30163676,13.74,-3.80176,43.46192
3,78.00,2013-04-01 00:28:54,30163676,13.74,-3.80176,43.46192
4,78.00,2013-04-01 00:13:07,30164278,13.67,-3.80176,43.46192
4,78.00,2013-04-01 00:28:01,30163676,13.74,-3.80176,43.46192
5,78.00,2013-04-01 00:13:31,30163676,13.74,-3.80176,43.46192
5,78.00,2013-04-01 00:28:26,30164875,13.67,-3.80176,43.46192
6,78.00,2013-04-01 00:12:52,30164875,13.67,-3.80176,43.46192
6,78.00,2013-04-01 00:28:52,30164875,13.67,-3.80176,43.46192',header=TRUE,
                tz='',sep=',',index=3)
```

Then you create and save your list by group,

```
library(xts)
df2 <- by(dat,dat$nodeId,function(x){
  ends <- endpoints(x, on = "minutes", k = 1)
  xx    <- period.apply(x, ends, mean)
})

write.table(do.call(rbind,df2),file='test.csv')
```

To read it again you do just

```
read.table('test.csv')
                      nodeId battery idHistoric temperature longitude latitude
3.2013-04-01 00:13:59      3      78   30163676       13.74  -3.80176 43.46192
3.2013-04-01 00:28:54      3      78   30163676       13.74  -3.80176 43.46192
4.2013-04-01 00:13:07      4      78   30164278       13.67  -3.80176 43.46192
4.2013-04-01 00:28:01      4      78   30163676       13.74  -3.80176 43.46192
5.2013-04-01 00:13:31      5      78   30163676       13.74  -3.80176 43.46192
5.2013-04-01 00:28:26      5      78   30164875       13.67  -3.80176 43.46192
6.2013-04-01 00:12:52      6      78   30164875       13.67  -3.80176 43.46192
6.2013-04-01 00:28:52      6      78   30164875       13.67  -3.80176 43.46192
```

**EDIT** to save/ and read it again  as a zoo objects, I transform sligthly the rownames of the binded list:

```
dd <- do.call(rbind,df2)
rownames(dd) <- gsub('*.[.]','',rownames(dd))
write.table(dd,file='test.csv')
```

Now I can read this again :

```
read.zoo('test.csv',index=0,tz='')
                    nodeId battery idHistoric temperature longitude latitude
2013-04-01 00:12:52      6      78   30164875       13.67  -3.80176 43.46192
2013-04-01 00:13:07      4      78   30164278       13.67  -3.80176 43.46192
2013-04-01 00:13:31      5      78   30163676       13.74  -3.80176 43.46192
2013-04-01 00:13:59      3      78   30163676       13.74  -3.80176 43.46192
2013-04-01 00:28:01      4      78   30163676       13.74  -3.80176 43.46192
2013-04-01 00:28:26      5      78   30164875       13.67  -3.80176 43.46192
2013-04-01 00:28:52      6      78   30164875       13.67  -3.80176 43.46192
2013-04-01 00:28:54      3      78   30163676       13.74  -3.80176 43.46192
```

**EDIT2**

Thanks to @Gsee excellent answer you can do the following :

```
do.call(rbind, unname(df2))
```

This will keep the row names right, so no need to use a regular expression as I did in my previous edit.

Comment: +1 already.  I've been trying to figure out how to get the row names right.  Other than using `gsub` like you did, the closest I've gotten is with `data.table`: `write.csv(rbindlist(lapply(df2, as.data.table, keep.rownames=TRUE)), row.names=TRUE)`.

Comment: Ah.  How about this: `do.call(rbind, unname(df2))`?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at `str(df2)`, you'll see that it is a named `list`.  Generally, when you have a list and you want to convert it into a single object, you can use something like `do.call(rbind, df2)`.  This is the same as `rbind(df2[[1]], df2[[2]], df2[[3]], df2[[4]])`, but will work with a list of any length.

In this case, your `list` has `names`

```
> names(df2)
[1] "3" "4" "5" "6"
```

So, if you just `do.call(rbind, df2)`, the `rownames` will not be quite what you want -- they'll be prepended with the `names` of the list.

```
> rownames(do.call(rbind, df2))
[1] "3.2013-04-01 00:13:59" "3.2013-04-01 00:28:54" "4.2013-04-01 00:13:07"
[4] "4.2013-04-01 00:28:01" "5.2013-04-01 00:13:31" "5.2013-04-01 00:28:26"
[7] "6.2013-04-01 00:12:52" "6.2013-04-01 00:28:52"
```

The solution is to `unname` the list

```
do.call(rbind, unname(df2))
```

Since you're working with `xts`, you're probably going to want to coerce that to an `xts` object:

```
> as.xts(do.call(rbind, unname(df2)))
                    nodeId battery idHistoric temperature longitude latitude
2013-04-01 00:12:52      6      78   30164875       13.67  -3.80176 43.46192
2013-04-01 00:13:07      4      78   30164278       13.67  -3.80176 43.46192
2013-04-01 00:13:31      5      78   30163676       13.74  -3.80176 43.46192
2013-04-01 00:13:59      3      78   30163676       13.74  -3.80176 43.46192
2013-04-01 00:28:01      4      78   30163676       13.74  -3.80176 43.46192
2013-04-01 00:28:26      5      78   30164875       13.67  -3.80176 43.46192
2013-04-01 00:28:52      6      78   30164875       13.67  -3.80176 43.46192
2013-04-01 00:28:54      3      78   30163676       13.74  -3.80176 43.46192
```

Finally, I find it convenient to use `write.zoo` to write csv files of `xts` or `zoo` objects:

```
write.zoo(as.xts(do.call(rbind, unname(df2))), file="test.csv", sep=",")
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

xts returns a vector. I had to iterate through every position (using while) and write every element into a csv file.

```
df2 <- by(df,df$nodeId,function(x){
   ends <- endpoints(x, on = "minutes", k = 15)
   xx    <- period.apply(x, ends, mean)
})

i <- 1

total <- length(df2)

while( i <= total ){
    write.csv(df2[i],paste("lights_2013-04-0102/out_",i,".csv",sep = ""))
    i <- i + 1
}
```